Show an image at some location on a point cloud using Open3D
So I have a point cloud which I can show on the screen using Open3D's examples. However, now I have an image and I need to show that image on a specific coordinate on the point cloud. I can't find any example about how to do this. Does anyone know how it can be done ? Thank you very much.

Directly adding the image as o3d.geometry.Image to visualizer will set the image as background for the visualizer. To do what you want, a good idea would be to make a mesh using pixels. Each pixel acts as a mesh vertex and each 4 neighbouring vertex will make 2 triangles in the mesh.

@saurabheights: Hi, I don't want to set image as background for the visualizer. I want to show the image on a small 2d plane at some specific coordinate in the 3d point cloud. I'm not sure I understand your point about the mesh, can you explain further please ? I'm sorry if my questions seem silly, but i'm very new to this library and point cloud in general.

See the answer below.

One way to display an image is by converting the image to a mesh. Here, we can use TriangleMesh or TetraMesh. I have used TriangleMesh here.
A TriangleMesh is basically a list of vertices in 3D with a list of faces/traingles. Each traingle is a set of 3 vertex indices defining which vertex to connect.
Now, imagine an image hanging in a 3D world. Each pixel of this image is a vertex for the mesh. And you can define triangles by connecting positions (i,j), (i+1,j) and (i,j+1) to make one triangle and (i, j+1), (i+1,j) and (i+1,j+1) to make another triangle. Just make sure you skip the last row and last column, since there is no i+1 or j+1 for that.
See below answer, which will download a Bunny Mesh and an Image from open3d public assets and generate a mesh from image.
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(o3d.data.BunnyMesh().path)
pcd1 = mesh.sample_points_poisson_disk(10000)

img = o3d.io.read_image(o3d.data.JuneauImage().path)

def convert_image_to_mesh(img: np.ndarray):
    img = np.asarray(img)

    # Instead of backprojecting, just convert img to an actual 3D plane with Z=0

    # Create 3D vertex for each pixel location
    xvalues = np.arange(img.shape[1])
    yvalues = np.arange(img.shape[0])
    x_loc, y_loc = np.meshgrid(xvalues, yvalues)
    z_loc = np.zeros_like(x_loc)

    # Scale down before making 3D vertices
    x_loc = x_loc / xvalues.shape[0]
    y_loc = y_loc / xvalues.shape[0]  # Keep aspect ratio same by dividing with same denominator. Now image width is 1 meter in 3d.

    vertices = np.stack((x_loc, y_loc, z_loc), axis=2).reshape(-1, 3)

    vertex_colors = img.reshape(-1, 3)/255.0

    # Create triangles between each pair of neighboring vertices
    # Connect positions (i,j), (i+1,j) and (i,j+1) to make one triangle and (i, j+1), (i+1,j) and (i+1,j+1) to make
    # another triangle.
    # Pixel (i,j) is in vertices array at location i + j*xvalues.shape[0]

    vertex_positions = np.arange(xvalues.size * yvalues.size)
    # Reshape into 2D grid and discard last row and column
    vertex_positions = vertex_positions.reshape(yvalues.size, xvalues.size)[:-1, :-1].flatten()

    # Now create triangles (keep vertices in anticlockwise order when making triangles)
    top_triangles = np.vstack(((vertex_positions+1, vertex_positions, vertex_positions+xvalues.shape[0]))).transpose(1, 0)
    bottom_triangles = np.vstack(((vertex_positions+1, vertex_positions, vertex_positions+xvalues.shape[0]))).transpose(1, 0)

    triangles = np.vstack((top_triangles, bottom_triangles))

    mesh: o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh(
        o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(vertices), o3d.utility.Vector3iVector(triangles)
    )

    mesh.vertex_colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(vertex_colors)
    """
    Flip the y and z axis according to opencv to opengl transformation.
    See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375149/opencv-to-opengl-coordinate-system-transform
    """
    mesh.transform([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
    return mesh

visualizer = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
visualizer.create_window()

# Enable back face as we want to see image backside as well
rendering_options = visualizer.get_render_option()
rendering_options.mesh_show_back_face = True

visualizer.add_geometry(pcd1)

mesh = convert_image_to_mesh(img)
mesh.scale(scale=0.1, center=pcd1.get_center())
visualizer.add_geometry(mesh)
visualizer.run()


Hi, it works. I have another question. So my points are centered around [5.31e+05, 6.32e+06, 1.15e+02], when I show the point cloud I normalized the coordinates so that it will be close to zero for the first 2 coordinates (or else the quality would degrade). When I run your code, I noticed that if I put "mesh.scale(scale=30.0, center=np.array([0.0, -4.5, 0.0]))" then the images would show on the same plane as the point cloud. However, if I change the scale then it would no longer be like that. Do you know why is that ? Thanks a lot.

The values in the scale method are specific to the bunny location. When you scale, new x = scale * (oldx - x). I would suggest you use something like center=mesh.get_center()

Thank you very much, I have managed to fix it as you said. It turns out that previously, when I centered my point cloud, I did not center the z-axis that's why there was some discrepancies.

@DangManhTruong - Also, you can add text using similar approach, convert text of certain font to 3d mesh using inbuilt open3d method. See https://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.t.geometry.TriangleMesh.html#open3d.t.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_text
